# Using objective c project in swift 3 using pod

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, swift3

I am working on my project in swift and need to use https://github.com/xebia-france/SMWheelControl .This project is written in objective c. I made a pod of the project and in bridging header used

```
#import "SMWheelControl.h"
```

I have linked my storyboard with SpinnViewController and used the protocol SMWheelControlDataSource, SMWheelControlDelegate. And this is the functions I wrote in my SpinViewcontroller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        var wheel = SMWheelControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 320))

        wheel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.wheelDidChangeValue), for: .valueChanged)

        wheel.dataSource = self
        wheel.reloadData()

    }

    func numberOfSlices(inWheel wheel: SMWheelControl!) -> UInt {

         return 10
    }

    func wheel(_ wheel: SMWheelControl!, viewForSliceAt index: UInt) -> UIView! {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 30))
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        label.text! = " \(index)"
        return label

    }
```

It keeps giving me error 'value of type 'SpinViewController'has no member 'wheelDidChangeValue'. What am I doing wrong? Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue

```
#selector(self.wheelDidChangeValue)
```

You added this function in selector and is not implemented in your view controller. Just add

```
func wheelDidChangeValue() {

}
```

in your SpinnViewController

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Then what do I write inside the function? I implemented the code by reading the DOCS written in objective c. Have no idea how to implement that in swift.

Comment: This function is actually called when an event (wheel value change) happens. So pls implement the this you want to do when the value is changed.

Comment: The error is gone and it compiles perfectly with a white screen in simulator. Do I need to connect the data source in storyboard screen. And how to reference it in spinviewcontroller

Comment: please do set delegate and datasource